# pass angularjs variable to jade while loop condition

Tags: pug

I want to pass angularjs variable {{test}} into jade while loop condition statement. I tried this:

```
ul
  - var i = 0
  while i < {{test}}
    li i++
```

but i got syntax error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Jade is server-side, Angular is client-side. When Angular is being run, Jade has already been executed long before. Passing variable from angular to jade is almost like passing variable back in time ;) can't happen. You should convert that entire Jade logic into Angular logic itself if you wanna use Angular variables.

Comment: thanks. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would sit down and think about this completely different. I can make this work, however it will be messy and uneccesary!

i assume test is an array?

Rewrite your ul tag to this:

```
ul(ng-repeat="t in test")
   li t
```

Tada! :)

This will cause angular to run through the whole array and create a li tag for each index in the array!

Comment: oh, I just use the ng-repeat way. I thought Jade can be client side, turns out it was wrong. Thanks.